# how to make mediaQuery over write values which were set dynamically in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which has a basic width value, set in a css file. 
In that file, i also have a media query for a new basic width, upon orientation change to portrait.
in my javaScript i have a function updating the width dynamically when document is ready.

What happens is, that when the media query is called, the updated width - is the width which was set dynamically by the js, and it's automatically overwrites the new media query css width.
In other words, once I dynamically set the width in the code - the media query will no longer take any effect.

how can i make the media query css width overwrite the current width (which was set dynamically by js?)

THANK YOU!

---

HTML + JS :

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script>
        var defaultNumOfItem = 3;

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
             updateWidth(4);
        });

        function updateWidth(currentNumOfItems) {
            var basicWidthText = $('#list').css('width');
            var basicWidth = parseFloat(basicWidthText .slice(0, basicWidthText .indexOf('px')));
            $('#list').css('width', basicWidth * currentNumOfItems/ defaultNumOfItem);
        }

        $(window).bind('orientationchange, function(){
            updateWidth(4);
        });
     </script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id='list'>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#list {
   width: 900px;
}

@media only screen  and (orientation: portrait){

    #list {
       width: 600px;
    }

}
```

P.S the use of !important did not work for me, since if i put it in the css - the js will take no effect. and if i put it in the js - the media query takes no effect - same will happen by putting it in both the js and the css

Comment: Good question. As far as I know, the Browser will always render the inline Styles first. Then Header Styles, then External. So basically header css overrides external css, and inline css overrides header css.

Comment: So what do i do? 
what i need, is to know the width written in the css file.
How can i do that if i have a width value that kills all the others?

btw, css from a file.css - does it considered as external? and if so, what is stronger? that one, or the css set in the javaScript?

Comment: The style you set in your Javascript are inline (thats what I've learned, if this is wrong, please correct me), so they override the external css (which is a .css file), unless there is some !important style definition. I know that this is no answer, thats why I just wrote a comment, but I thought it might helps you understanding the hierarchy of css. I'm very interested in an answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be achieved without JavaScript, though the full intent of the code is not totally clear, so this is how to do it while maintaining the current functionality.

```
@media only screen  and (orientation: portrait) {

    #list {
        max-width: 600px;
    }

}
```

The `max-width` CSS property trumps `width`, even if `width` is defined inline, externally, or made `!important`. The same is true of the `min-width` property under different circumstances.

Comment: obviously the code is a small part of a huge mobile application.
But your solution might work. 
I'll try that, thanks! :)
Yet, it is quiet a workaround. isn't there anything else i could use for the same effect?

Comment: This is not a workaround. This is how CSS works. Your requirements are exactly the use case that would have prompted the need for such an addition to CSS2 in the first place.

Comment: wait, when i think about it, how can it work? what if i have a list of 4 items? then the updated width should be 600 * 4/3 which is more then 600...

Comment: Your example shows a hardcoded value of `600px` in the media query. If the value is in fact dynamically generated somehow, or wrong, you need to state that. That is a problem with the question. Consider actually trying the solution, though. You do it no justice by entertaining hypotheticals; the browser's CSS interpreter is superior, I assure you.

Comment: On the css file it IS hard coded to 600px. yes. (I actually pre process it in php,so it might change to something else, but that's not the issue..)
I did mention in the question, that the whole point of my code is to have a basic list, set up for a default value of 3 elements.
Every now and then, i get an update from the server about the number of element in the list, so i need to update the list's width.
So if i use max-width, it should be a problem, since i do need the list to expand indeed. 
Sorry if  i wasn't clear enough about that :)

Comment: If it fails to address the issue *after you have actually tried it*, I will revisit the question.

Comment: fair enough. Can't see how it can work, but i will give it a try.

Comment: Man, wish i could post a print screen in here.
This is my chrome inspect element view:
---------------------------------------------------
element.style {
    width: 742.666666666666666666667px;
}
--------------------------------------------------------
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait)
#favoriteGames ul {
    margin: 2.93335px;
    max-width: 340.732422px;
}
---------------------------

so it seems to not be limiting the width at all. how is that even possible?...

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try `!important`

```
@media only screen  and (orientation: portrait){
    #list {
       width: 600px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that. Thank you. But when i do that - the updateWidth function takes no effect...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you want to use the media query only if orientation is portrait and the js if the orientation is landscape. In this case you can try this:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event){
       if(event.orientation != "portrait")
           updateWidth(4);
});
```

this way the js will not overwrite the width that you wanted to set through the media query in portrait

Comment: Thanks, but it's actually not what i intended to do. 
I have 2 basic widths, set up for a list of 3 elements - one for landscape and one for portrait.
once the document is ready, i divide the basic width by 3, and multiply by a number of elements got from the server - and that would be the new width. 
That way, I get a list of elements with dynamically changed width.
I do that for either orientation.

Comment: Since you can't really set the width from both js and media queries, (because the js sets the rules inline and will always override the media queries) you should implement the media queries rules functionality inside the js. Much more work but it will work

Comment: example:  $(window).resize(function () {
        // do what media queries would do
    });

Comment: no good for me either....
I should probably mention that i pre-process the css file in a php that multiplies all the values by delta according to the screen size. (All the values are set for a 2024 X 1536 screen)
So you see, i can't use raw numbers in the js....
Sorry for being so difficult.. :)

Comment: Maybe get the width and height of the viewport on page load and use these values to dynamically set the rest of the rules on your js. If you do pre process values on css then in js it should be easier

Comment: yeah... this is just what i was afraid of doing... 
getting the viewport width and height in 2 different places in the application is so risky and forms an opening for UI bugs.
But I guess there is not much of a choice...

Comment: on the bright side, it could mean better control when the user resizes the browser though (with even more work...). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a work around that actually works!

What i do, is simply remove the "width" attribute from the #list every time the orientation changes:

```
    $(window).bind('orientationchange, function(){
        $('#list').css('width','');
        updateWidth(4);
    });
```

so that way, the external css does take before the js manipulation.